# Opencv haar cascade negative images

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, haar-classifier

I want to make an object detector with OpenCV `haarcascade`. When my project is working, the background will be always white.

How should I add negative images?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65537229/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: csn you show some sample images of your application? If the background is always white, why do you need a trained detector at all? Isnt contour extraction much faster then?

Comment: I want to detect unknown objects like leafs, screws, pits or ripe olives from among healthy olives.

Comment: so your negative images should be images without those objects. E.g. if your target objects are ripe olives, your negative images might be unripe olives etc.

Comment: Thank you, it is working :)